# How to use html() and toContain() with shallowMount in Vue with some div containing another component?

Tags: vue.js, components, vue-test-utils

I have problem with shallowMount in Vue.

My function looks like this:

```
describe('ParentComponent.vue', () => {
  it('renders a ParentComponent', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(ParentComponent, {
      propsData: {
        propOne: 'someUrl',
        propTwo: 'someText'
      }
    });
    expect(wrapper.find('.some-class').html()).toContain(
      '<div alt="someText" class="some-class" style="width: 2rem; height: 2rem; background-image: url(propOne);"></div>'
    );
  });
});
```

ParentComponent looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div
    :style="basicStyles"
    :alt="title"
    class="some-class"
  >
    <ChildComponent v-if="someCondition"
      :someProp="something"
      :anotherProp="alsoSomething"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

In previous version of my ParentComponent there wasn't ChildComponent inside. Now I have to do it, but I don't know what should be inside toContain() method now. Because now it doesn't work, because expected substring is different from received string  in describe method. How to inject ChildComponet inside toContain() method if I want to test only ParentComponent?

Answer (score 1):

`shallowMount` stubs all the children components. You either use `mount` instead or do this

```
expect(wrapper.findComponent(ChildComponent).exists()).toBe(true)
```